# On Generalizations of Fermat's Conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, conjectures

We know the following facts:

**(1)** For all $1\leq n\leq 2$ the equation $x_{1}^{n}+x_{2}^{n}=x_{3}^{n}$ has a solution in $\mathbb{N}$.

**(2)** For all $3\leq n$ the equation $x_{1}^{n}+x_{2}^{n}=x_{3}^{n}$ has no solution in $\mathbb{N}$.

**Question:** Is the following generalization true?

For all $2\leq m$ both of the following statements are true:

**(1)** For all $1\leq n\leq m$ the equation $x_{1}^{n}+...+x_{m}^{n}=x_{m+1}^{n}$ has a solution in $\mathbb{N}$.

**(2)** For all $m+1\leq n$ the equation $x_{1}^{n}+...+x_{m}^{n}=x_{m+1}^{n}$ has no solution in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: That has been first conjectured by Euler, but much later proved to be wrong, see the answers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No this is not true. For $n=4$ one has 
$$2682440^4 + 15365639^4 + 18796760^4 = 20615673^4$$
found by Elkies (as part of an infinite family of solutions).
Also earlier  it was known, for example, for $n=5$, 
$$27^5 + 84^5 + 110^5 + 133^5 = 144^5$$
by Lander and Parkin.

But part 2 was a [conjecture of Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture) so you are in good company, and $n \ge 6$ is still open. See that page for further details.

Comment: wow! The world of numbers is the world of wonders! Thanks dear quid.

Comment: You are welcome! One thing to note is that direct extrapolation from Fermat can be risky since for $n=3$ there actually should be solutions on certain heuristic grounds. See an [answer of Elkies to a question on heuristically false theorems](http://mathoverflow.net/a/103493/9072) for this and also information directly related to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your useful references. I am just a passenger from Cantor's heaven in your wonderful realm.

Answer (score 10):

The smallest counterexample for $n = 4$ is
$95800^4 + 217519^4 + 414560^4 = 422481^4$.
This has been found out by Roger Frye in 1988, cf.
http://euler.free.fr/docs/euler88.ps.